# How to measure a signal that uses a virtual ground using Arduino

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, active-filter, eeg

I've created an EEG system that measures the potential difference between:

1) The differential amplification between EEG voltages.
2) a virtual ground between two 9V batteries.

I'm trying to measure the output of this EEG system using an Arduino, but I'm not sure how to do this since the Arduino and the EEG circuit are both using different grounds. (there is a gronud electrode plugged into the virtual ground as well)

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What is the range of the amplifier output? I.E. what are the max and min voltages it can output?

Comment: It outputs 0-9 V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to connect the virtual ground at the midpoint between the 2 batteries to the ground on the Arduino - as long as you are using batteries and not a power supply and there are no other connections between the two circuits that would cause a current loop.

An Arduino analog-to-digital input pin can only be connected to a max of 5 volts, so you will need to divide the output of the amplifier to fit in this range. A resistor-based voltage divider with 2 equal resistors will bring the 0-9V down to 0-4.5V, which is a good match for the Arduino.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1TlCB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I was worried I couldn't connect the virtual ground with the Arduino ground. Really appreciate your help (especially the extra effort put into the circuit diagram), this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad it made sense! Do heed the "and there are no other connections between the two circuits that would cause a current loop" warning - if there are other connections between the two systems besides the ground and the amp output you could get a way for current to flow and cause problems!

Comment: Here's my whole circuit for reference: https://ibb.co/GnQ3jHH

Comment: Not enough resolution for me to be able to read the part numbers, but I assume you are connecting the Arduino pin to the phono jack in the schematic? If so, then maybe confirm that the output there is actually 0-9V before connecting to the Arduino pin.